# Crystal reports messing up data base connections

Tags: crystal-reports

I am doing some data base development work in which Crystal Reports v. 14 is used as the reporting engine (Not my choise!). In the work, I am switching CRs database connection back and forth between my development and test databases (using database Set Database location) when thing started to act weird. When looking into the SQL, I found that CR is connecting some tables to the development database (lims-dev) and other tables to the test-database (lims-opplæring) even though in the database (socalled) expert, all the tables are shown to be connected at one or the other. A part of the sql:

```
FROM   (("lims-dev"."dbo"."RESULT" "Volume" INNER JOIN (("LIMS-OPPLÆRING"."dbo"."ORDERS" 
"ORDERS" LEFT OUTER JOIN "LIMS-OPPLÆRING"."dbo"."SAMPLE" "SAMPLE" ON "ORDERS"."ORDER_NUM"="SAMPLE"."X_ORDER") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "LIMS-  OPPLÆRING"."dbo"."TEST" "TEST" ON "SAMPLE"."SAMPLE_NUMBER"="TEST"."SAMPLE_NUMBER") 
ON ("Volume"."SAMPLE_NUMBER"="TEST"."SAMPLE_NUMBER") AND
```

And so on "lims-dev"."dbo"."RESULT" "Volume INNER JOIN (("LIMS-OPPLÆRING"."dbo"."ORDERS" ...

Is there any way to correct this, or has CR hosed my report and I just have to start over again?

Comment: Are all the tables listed under the same datasource under Set Datasource Location and are all added as tables, not as SQL-commands?

Comment: Yes and Yes  ... (I do some heavy filtering on some of the tables afterwards, but that should not matter at that stage, since as far as I can see, CR is just fetching all the data for me)

Comment: And if in the Set Datasource Location you look at the Table > Properties, what is in the Catalog-section?

Comment: You are on to something, Simo. There the wrong table is in the catalog section - but I cannot see any way to edit it...

Comment: In the Set Datasource Location you can re-set the location of individual tables so you can just choose the right database in the lower section. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks Simo, that did it - I didn't think about setting the data source for each single tabl, just tried to exchange the data sources... If you could rewrite this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open *Database > Set Datasource Location...*
- If all the tables are showing up under the same connection they are using the same Connection string
- Click open *your_table > Properties*, check that the *Catalog* property is pointing to the right database and for those table that have the wrong *Catalog* property:

  - Click on the table
  - Select the table from the right database in the *Replace with:* section
  - Click Update